# SAPUI5 Fileuploader upload not triggered if file to upload is set via setValue

Tags: file-upload, sapui5

In SAPUI5 I am using fileuploader to to upload file to gateway service.

Functionality works if I select file using by pressing "Browse" button, however if I set file path using using `setValue()` and after that call `upload()` function, file upload is not triggered. There are no errors in the browser.

This is the same behavior if I press upload button, but file path is not set. I suspect that there something additional that I need to set, but I have no idea what is that. Below is the code

UI

```
<u:FileUploader id="fileUploader" 
                tooltip="Select file to upload" 
                width="415px" 
                icon="sap-icon://add-document"
                uploadOnChange="false" 
                sendXHR="true" 
                uploadUrl="/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZUPLOAD_DOC_SRV/Upload_DocSet" 
                useMultipart="false"
                uploadStart="onUploadStart" 
                uploadComplete="handleUploadComplete" 
                sameFilenameAllowed="true" 
                change="onChange"/>
```

Controller

```
var oFileUploader = this.byId("fileUploader");
oFileUploader.removeAllHeaderParameters(oCustomerHeaderToken);
oFileUploader.setValue("C:\\TEMP\\test.txt");           

oCustomerHeaderToken = new sap.ui.unified.FileUploaderParameter({
    name: "x-csrf-token",
    value: oFileUploader.getModel().getSecurityToken()
});

oFileUploader.addHeaderParameter(oCustomerHeaderToken);
var oSlug = new sap.ui.unified.FileUploaderParameter({
        name: "slug",
        value: slugTemp
    });


oFileUploader.addHeaderParameter(oSlug);
oFileUploader.upload();
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons this is not allowed in JavaScript by Browsers. This has nothing to do with UI5, it is a general security measure.

If it was allowed a script could access ALL your files by generating random paths, read them and upload them to ANY server.

In some browsers it's possible to [access a sandboxed environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API) but it's unlikely that this will help you.

Accessing the complete hard drive is impossible (at the moment).